# Constantly sending SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I don't know if this a common question asked, but if it is, please don't yell at me! :(

I have a Windows Form C# program that executes an UPDATE query every 2 seconds with the threading timer.

My question is: is this dangerous?  Will this make my computer run much slower?  Am I firing up the CPU usage?  I'm a pretty concerned guy when it comes to constantly using something every second.

EDIT: It's UPDATE, not INSERT     sorry!

Comment: This is very dangerous. Your computer is likely to explode.

Comment: Just kidding. No it isn't dangerous at all. Though why would you execute an insert query every 2 seconds and not just immediately?

Comment: 1)  Yes.  2)  Depends on how fast your hardware is.  3)  Yes.  Everything uses the CPU to some extent, even playing Minesweeper.

Comment: Your clock speed is roughly 1 sec; your computer's is roughly 10ns. For your computer to perform an action every 2 sec is roughly equivalent to your computer performing an action every thirty years. I don't worry about the timing, or even the scheduling, of task I perform every thirty years or so, and neither should you.

Comment: What good is the CPU if it isn't being used?

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be UPDATE, instead of INSERT.
I mean, I could do 5 seconds, but nothing more.  I'm sure I can make some exceptions so it wouldn't have to update similar information.

Comment: What are you updating every 2 seconds? I'm not saying this is dangerous, I'm saying we can give you a better answer if you explain what has motivated this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer completely depends on the amount of work the update statement is performing. If it is updating millions of rows every two seconds, then it will definitely impact the performance.

However, if you are only updating a handful of rows (up to say, 100,000) in an SQL Server database, then this frequency should be perfectly acceptable.

The manner in which the update is performed is also important: using cursors, linked servers, CLR functions, databases other than SQL (i.e. Access), and many, many other factors can all significantly impact the performance.

Comment: I really apologize for such a vague information in the original post.  The program updates only 1 row, unique to the ones that are using this program.  Considering your post, I would say this is highly safe.  Thanks for your response!

Comment: @user1880591: not a problem. One row every two seconds is very safe, even in Access :).

Answer (score 2):

This always depends a lot on the size of the operation that is done every 2 seconds; if the operation takes 1.5 seconds to pre-process, execute and post-process, then it will be a problem. If it takes 4ms, probably not. You also need to think about the server; even if we say it takes 4ms, that could be parallelised over 8 cores, so that is 32ms - and if you have 2000 users *all* doing that every 2 seconds, it starts to add up.

But by itself: fine.

And client-side, on a modern multi-core PC, this is probably not even enough to register as the tiniest blip on the graph.

Comment: +1. on even more modern lower-power-consumption battery-powered tablet/laptop/phone it could drain battery in no time by preventing it to go to low-power modes... :) (not really serious - I'm not even sure it'll happen)

Comment: Thanks for this well-described point.  I will definitely keep this in mind.